# Examine transformation properties of functions under symmetry operations

Tags: group-theory

I need help learn how to examine transformation of a functions under a symmetry operation. For example, applying reflection in x axis on a vector (x,y)
 $$
(x,y).\begin{bmatrix} 
    1&0\\
0&-1 \end{bmatrix}=(x,-y)
$$ 
from which we know how x and y transform under reflection. My question is how to examine what happens to other functions such as $x^2$, $xy$, $x^2+y^2$.. etc, under the same operation?
Also, how to find matrix representations of the operation for these functions?
Thank you,
eftrsd

Answer (score 1):

In this case the simple way is to just replace $y$ with $-y$ in each of those.

However, it worth learning this sooner or later, for more complicated transformations.

$\mathbf x^TA\mathbf x$ can represent these quadratics.

$\pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}\pmatrix{x\\y} = x^2\\
\pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{0&\frac 12\\\frac 12&0}\pmatrix{x\\y} = xy$

etc.  Note that A is symmetric.

Now to transform $(x,y)$ replace

$\pmatrix{x&y}$ with $\pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ and 
$\pmatrix{x\\y}$ with $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}^{T}\pmatrix{x\\y}$